# Is it possible to erase drawing made by NSRectFill?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, draw, erase, rect

I have been using `NSRectFill` to draw rectangles on the screen. I would like to erase these rectangles. I can't paint over them, as the back ground behind them is textured and can't be replicated with a solid color. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know much Objective-C, or Cocoa, so I can't give you details, but here's how my Windows oriented mind thinks:

Simply request a redrawing of the window, and then don't paint the rectangles.

Comment: Cocoa works the same way. Just keep a mutable array of your rectangles, and to erase one or more of them delete it from the array and call `[theView setNeedsDisplay:YES]` to trigger a redraw of `theView`. In the view's `-drawRect:` method, just draw the background, then loop through the rectangle array and draw each of them.

Comment: You can also `setNeedsDisplayInRect:` and pass the rectangle that you're about to delete, then only redraw the background in that rectangle and only redraw any remaining rectangles that intersect it.

Answer (score 1):

Just draw the background again.